# Get user current permissions or group name in list item change workflow?

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, groups

In a workflow (with designer) on list/library item change events I want to get the current user's permissions, more specifically, the group name(s) to apply some conditions based on the permissions of the user.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [action in SharePoint 2013 workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform) to get the user groups & permissions.

**Workaround**:

Use SharePoint REST APIs to get the user permissions. You can call REST APIs from workflow using **Call HTTP Web Service** action.

Get groups of user by using user Id:

```
/_api/web/getuserbyid(<user-id>)?$expand=groups
```

Replace `<user-id>` by Id of user.

Follow below references to use REST API in workflow (you can easily find other articles related to this on google).

**References**:

1. [Calling Rest API From A SharePoint Designer Workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)
2. [CALLING THE SHAREPOINT 2013 REST API FROM A SHAREPOINT DESIGNER WORKFLOW](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)